# Subseting when there are n consecutive dummies

Tags: r, dplyr, subset, tibble

I have a data frame and I have created a series of dummy variables and then combined them into i final column. I want to know if I have a case where there is 3 consecutive 1's, i.e., is there a way to subset the data frame that gives me rows 3:5 in the following example?

```
df <-  tibble(
      a= c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1)
    )
df

# A tibble: 8 x 1
      a
  <dbl>
1     0
2     0
3     1
4     1
5     1
6     0
7     1
8     1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The package `data.table` has a nice function called `rleid` that creates groups based on the `diff` not being 0. Using that, you can do,

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
 group_by(grp = data.table::rleid(df$a)) %>% 
 filter(n() >= 3 & all(a == 1))
```

Comment: @ Sotos. I was wondering if there exists a tidyverse solution without data.table.